# Ajax no me trae los datos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, poo

les comento mi problema estoy tratando de editar un registro y los datos los mando llamar a través de un id con Js y funciona.

Pero después de enviar ese id con Ajax a través de `"POST"` a un método para que se encargue de realizar la consulta y me devuelva los valores, me manda un error en el método, y el error es en un `"if"` pero aún no entiendo porque.

Y por cierto que al enviar los datos por ajax, tenía `dataType:"json"` pero lo comente porque no me mostraba nada.

Les dejo el código para que me puedan ayudar...

usuarios.js (Js y Ajax):

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditarUsuario", function(){

   var idUsuario = $(this).attr("idUsuario");
   console.log("idUsuario", idUsuario); //Mandando llamar el id con la consola

   //AJAX
   var datos = new FormData();
   datos.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);

  $.ajax({

       url:"../ajax/usuarios.ajax.php",
       method: "POST",
       data: datos,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       //dataType: "json",
       success: function(respuesta){

           console.log("respuesta", respuesta);

       }

   });  })
```

El resultado en la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente en el if del final es donde está el supuesto error que me aparece en la consola, únicamente lo que hago es a traves del metodo consultar los datos con el id que mando desde el post de Ajax y aquí ejecutarlo.

```
require_once "../controladores/usuarios.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/usuarios.modelo.php";

class AjaxUsuarios{

/*=============================================
EDITAR USUARIO
=============================================*/ 

public $idUsuario;

public function ajaxEditarUsuario(){

    $item = "idusuario";
    $valor = $this->idUsuario;

    $respuesta = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor);


    echo json_encode($respuesta);

}//Cierra funcion

   }//Cierra clase
// EDITAR USUARIO AQUI ES EL ERROR

if(isset($_POST["idUsuario"])){

$editar = new AjaxUsuarios();
$editar -> idUsuario = $_POST["idUsuario"];
$editar -> ajaxEditarUsuario();
}
```

Esta es la clase que estoy llamando con el HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-warning btnEditarUsuario"  
    idUsuario="'.$value["idusuario"].'" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#modalEditarUsuario"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>

   <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>

 </div>
```

Lo que ahora me muestra en consola son los datos que requiero resaltados en color rojo, lo demas es del HTML:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***ACTUALIZACIÓN RESUELTO***

Consola, los datos que esperaba obtener:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo JS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tiene que descomenta el json *** dataType: 'json',***

Comment: deberias ejecutar tu codigo en postman y probablemente vas a ver el retorno de tu codigo mas unos warning , esos warning debes corregirlo ya que el ajax por defecto toma el context-type = json

Comment: No veo la lleve de cierre de la clase (que debería ir justo después del de cierre de la función).

Comment: Debes cerrar la clase: `public function ajaxEditarUsuario(){

    $item = "idusuario";
    $valor = $this->idUsuario;

    $respuesta = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor);


    echo json_encode($respuesta);

}}`  y quitar la llave de cierre que sobra en el `if`, dejando sólo una.

Comment: @marcosalbertosaavedrasanabr si descomento la línea de `dataType: "json",` solo me aparece el id de la consola, no me aparece nada más.

Comment: @A.Cedano es correcto me trajo los datos y algunos errores en el html

Comment: No es bueno mezclar. Tu clase debería estar en un archivo aparte. Otra cosa es que, el código debe estar controlado para que imprima por pantalla el JSON esperado y nada más. Como los `include` que haces saquen algo por pantalla, te fastidia todo. El código que se usa con Ajax y que espera una respuesta JSON debe estar controlado en todo momento y responder siempre, aún en el caso de errores, una respuesta en forma de JSON. O cambias el `dataType: "html"`, eso dependerá siempre del uso que le vayas a dar a la respuesta. Y aún así, siempre debes controlar las salidas por pantalla, siempre.

Comment: De acuerdo cambiare algunos detalles para mejorar la respuesta del json

Comment: @A.Cedano Me ha funcionado los errores del HTML, no eran del HTML eran de las clases y ahora tengo un problema con ello pero lo hare en otro post, por ahora gracias dejo la actualizacion con los datos funcionando :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba estas correcciones:

### PHP

El `if` no es parte de la clase. Por tanto, la clase debe cerrar al final de la función `ajaxEditarUsuario`.

En cualquier caso, es un código que conviene separar, teniendo siempre tu clase aparte.

```
/*
   *Si alguno de estos dos archivos del require sacan algo por pantalla 
   *tu petición Ajax no funcionará de la manera esperada. 
   *Las peticiones Ajax se suelen hacer para obtener cosas muy concretas
   *cualquier otra cosa que salga por pantalla, aparte de lo que se está pidiendo
   *por ejemplo un mensaje de error, contenido HTML, un `echo, print` u otro
   *hará que el código devuelva otros datos que no son los esperados
   *es de suma importancia controlar eso
*/


require_once "../controladores/usuarios.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/usuarios.modelo.php";

class AjaxUsuarios{

/*=============================================
EDITAR USUARIO
=============================================*/ 

    public $idUsuario;

    public function ajaxEditarUsuario(){

        $item = "idusuario";
        $valor = $this->idUsuario;

        $respuesta = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor);


        echo json_encode($respuesta);

    }
/*Cierre de la clase*/
} 

// EDITAR USUARIO AQUI ES EL ERROR

if(isset($_POST["idUsuario"])){

    $editar = new AjaxUsuarios();
    $editar -> idUsuario = $_POST["idUsuario"];
    $editar -> ajaxEditarUsuario();
}
```

### JS

Descomentas el `dataType`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditarUsuario", function(){

   var idUsuario = $(this).attr("idUsuario");
   console.log("idUsuario", idUsuario); //Mandando llamar el id con la consola

   //AJAX
   var datos = new FormData();
   datos.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);

  $.ajax({

       url:"../ajax/usuarios.ajax.php",
       method: "POST",
       data: datos,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(respuesta){

           console.log("respuesta", respuesta);

       }

   });  })
```

Answer (score 1):

la cuestion es que en el controlador tiene un if fuerar de una funcion

require_once "../controladores/usuarios.controlador.php";
    require_once "../modelos/usuarios.modelo.php";

```
class AjaxUsuarios{

/*=============================================
EDITAR USUARIO
=============================================*/ 

    public $idUsuario;

    public function ajaxEditarUsuario(){



    $item = "idusuario";
            $valor = $this->idUsuario;

            $respuesta = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor);


            echo json_encode($respuesta);

        }
    }


    /

    / EDITAR USUARIO AQUI ES EL ERROR

    public function ajaxEditarUsuariedita_datos(){
     if(isset($_POST["idUsuario"])){
            $editar = new AjaxUsuarios();
            $editar -> idUsuario = $_POST["idUsuario"];
            $editar -> ajaxEditarUsuario();
    }  
}
```